# Kendo Grid Custom Reordering

Tags: drag-and-drop, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid UI. The following is an example of the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.common.min.css"   rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1324/styles/kendo.dataviz.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="/kendo-ui/content/shared/styles/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <div id="main">
<h1 id="exampleTitle">
        <span class="exampleIcon gridIcon"></span>
        <strong>Grid /</strong> Column resizing    </h1>

<div id="theme-list-container"></div>

<div id="exampleWrap">
    <script>preventFOUC()</script>


    <div id="example" class="k-content">
        <div id="grid"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                                        read: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                                    },
                                });
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: gridDataSource,
                    scrollable: true,
                    resizable: true,

                    columns: [
                       {
                            field: "OrderID",
                            title: "ID"

                        }, {
                            field: "OrderDate",
                            title: "Order Date"


                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShipCountry",
                            title: "Ship Country"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShipCity",
                            title: "Ship City"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShipName",
                            title: "Ship Name"

                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShippedDate",
                            title: "Shipped Date"

                        }

                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want a customized reorder on columns. I have disabled drag and drop on OrderID. But columns other than OrderID can be reordered and these columns can be placed before OrderID column.

Is there a way where I can disable dropping of columns before OrderID?

Comment: Also `$("#grid").find("columnId").kendoDraggable();` disables dragging the specified columnId? It does work, but I mean, Is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: If you can place a column _before_ `columnId`, what is the difference with allowing to move `columnId`? I might understand that you want to have `objectId` as first column but not allowing to move it but allowing to put other both before and after is confusing.

Comment: I don't want users to move `columnId`. Also I don;t want to allow them to put other columns before `columnId`(_i.e., first column_).

Comment: By the end of the question you say _ But columns other than OrderID can be reordered and these columns can be placed before OrderID column._...

Comment: Yes. And after that I have asked my question. That is "Is there a way where I can disable dropping of columns before OrderID?". :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do it in two steps:

1. Disable dropping into first column.
2. Disable dragging first column.

For the first part after creating the grid you can do:

```
$("th:nth(0)", "#grid").data("kendoDropTarget").destroy();
```

This gets from a grid which identifier is `grid` and the first head cell `th:nth(0)` the KendoUI `DropTarget` and destroys it (no longer a valid drop target).

For the second part, you should define a `dragstart` event that checks that you are dragging the first column and if so, you do not allow to drag it.

```
$("#grid").data("kendoDraggable").bind("dragstart", function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.text() === "ID") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

*NOTE*: Here I detected the first column asking for its text (`ID`) but you might change it to check for its position in the list of `th` in the grid and if so invoke `preventDefault`.

Check it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/jzZ4u/1/

Answer (score 0):

check this for more elegant implementation:

```
kendo.ui.Grid.fn._reorderable = function (reorderable) {
    return function () {
        reorderable.call(this);

        var dropTargets = $(this.element).find('th.disable-reorder');

        dropTargets.each(function (idx, item) {
            $(item).data("kendoDropTarget").destroy();
        });

        var draggable = $(this.element).data("kendoDraggable");

        if (draggable) {

            draggable.bind("dragstart", function (e) {
                if ($(e.currentTarget).hasClass("disable-reorder"))
                    e.preventDefault();
            });

        }
    }
}(kendo.ui.Grid.fn._reorderable);
```

where .disable-reorder class is for disabling column